# How do I create a recursive one-to-many relationship using core data?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, cocoa, core-data

I have used core data before, but this database I have to construct has a particularity that will require a special relationship that is melting my brain.

I have 2 entities, lets call them Cage and Animal.

- Cage has one attribute `name`
- Animal has a `name` and `image` attributes and must keep track of its children.

A possible structure can be something like

```
cage ---------- animal 1
         |
         |_____ animal 2
         |
         |_____ animal 3 ____ animal 4
                          |
                          |__ animal 5
                                  |
                                  |_____ animal 6
```

Looking at this structure you see that `Animal 1`, `Animal 2` and `Animal 3` have `Cage` as parent or are "children" objects of Cage if you will. On the other hand `Animal 3` has 2 children objects (4 and 5) and `Animal 5` has one children object.

I need `Cage` and `Animal` to be different entities.

So, you see that `Animal` objects can have other Animals as children. An animal can have one parent but multiple children. A Cage object can only have children.

I have tried to add a `children` relationship with destination equal to Animal and inverse equal to `children` (toMany) but this is what is melting my brain, because if I do this, this will be parent at one time and children at others, not to mention that the name children will make coding difficult to wrap the head around...

How do I have to build the relationships between the entities to make this work?

Comment: What relations between `cage` and `animal 4`?

Comment: I think that your to-many relationship on the Animals entity on itself could be the right way to go. Once your relationships will be properly named childrens (many) and parent (one) you will be able to walk from an animal to another just by testing if there is an existing relationship property and so on... don't you think so ?

The main issue will be to write the proper algorithm to get a theorically un-defined number of parent-child relationships, but maybe you can put some limits here (ie no more than 5 parent-child levels)

Comment: @orkenstein - none. Animal 4 is a children of 3

Comment: @orkenstein : animal4.parent.cage ... I presume

Comment: Rule of database programming - if you're unsure, always go to-many or many-many.

Comment: Defaulting to many-to-many is an "anti-pattern", not a rule. In general they should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create your entities and attributes. Then create your relationships. The relationships for "animals" and "children" shout be set to "to many". Leave "cage" and "parent" set to "to one" relationship. Finally, set the destination and inverse for each relation.

Relations "animals" and "cage" should be inverse.
Relations "parent" and "children" should be set to inverse.

Should look like this when you're done:

[image]

Comment: My brain hurts but I see you have created a cage property and also a parent and a children. I was thinking incorrectly. I think this will do the trick! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also note, that when your code is looking at an `Animal` instance, either `cage` or `parent` should not be nil, but not both.

Comment: This is identical to my needs. Is there a way to make each recursive Animal object inherit the cage property of its parent? Or does that have to be set in code?

Comment: I just tried setting the cage property of animals programmatically, but that just makes all Animal objects direct descendent of Cage. I would like each animal to be associated with a cage without them having to be the first child. How could I set that up?

Answer (score 1):

Animals live on cage and two animals can have relationships.

[image: I came up with following ERD]

Comment: The many-to-many relationship for animal does not enforce the rule that an animal can only have one parent. It also requires additional storage for the relationship name for every record. It also makes it more difficult to "walk" the object structure, such as `animal6.parent.parent.cage`.

Comment: I was thinking of the flexibility of an animal having more than one relationship with other. In case of animals, you don't track husband/wife [ :) ], I guess. However, this gives the flexibility of say siblings, mother, father etc.Like you said, since it does not enforce all animals to have relationships (there might be no track record of one animal's parents or other relationships). For the last part, I believe animal6.parent.parent.cage is an unusual use case.