# How can an entity inherit a property in a recursive model structure?

Tags: ios, core-data, recursive-datastructures

I have a structure identical to this post here:
[How do I create a recursive one-to-many relationship using core data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516684/how-do-i-create-a-recursive-one-to-many-relationship-using-core-data)

It looks something like this:

```
    cage ---------- animal 1
             |
             |_____ animal 2
             |
             |_____ animal 3 ____ animal 4
                              |
                              |__ animal 5
                                      |
                                      |_____ animal 6
```

And I have implemented my models exactly as the correct answer has done, i.e.

[image]

The problem for me, is that with this structure, only `animal 1` has a non-nil property `cage`, but I would like ALL descendent animals to have this property `cage` so that i could query the cage property `animal6.cage`.

I've tried setting this manually but the inverse relationship causes any animal with a cage property to be a direct child of that cage, which I don't want.

Is it possible to inherit the cage property for each animal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using terms like "inherit" and "child" in ways that don't have meaning to Core Data. You have `Cage` which is related to `Animal`. `Animal` has a relationship to itself.

There's no parent/child relationship or inheritance here as far as Core Data is concerned. If one `Animal` is related to another, they're just two instances with a relationship. One can't inherit a value from the other because one is not the "parent" in any sense that Core Data uses. The two instances are two independent objects and they don't inherit anything any more than any two non-Core Data objects would.

Following from that, setting the `cage` property doesn't make an `Animal` a "direct child" of the cage, it just says it's related to the cage. If you want to find the `cage` for any arbitrary `Animal` without setting `cage` on every instance, you need to do something like (Swift-ish pseudocode):

```
func cage(for animal:Animal) -> Cage {
    var currentAnimal = animal
    var cage = currentAnimal.cage
    while cage == nil && currentAnimal.parent != nil {
        currentAnimal = currentAnimal.parent
        cage = currentAnimal.cage
    }
    return cage
}
```

That's fine if you just want to find the cage for an animal, but you can't use it in a fetch request. If you need something you can use when fetching, you probably need to add a second relationship from `Animal` to `Cage` so that you can distinguish the "parent" animal from any others. Every `Animal` would have a value for one of the relationships, and the other relationship would be reserved for the parent.

Comment: I figured I could do something like the function you posted - not sure what you meant by the last paragraph though

Comment: If you wanted to do something like fetch every animal in a particular cage, regardless of their parent/child status, you couldn't use the method in the answer-- you'd need a different approach. If you don't need to do that, then the function is what you need.